# Most efficient linear interpolation using integer fraction

Tags: compiler-optimization, avr, bit-shift, avr-gcc, linear-interpolation

I’m playing around with Direct digital synthesis wavetables on an Atmega328.

Given an 8-bit fractional value F, and two 8-bit values A, B, what would be the most efficient way to calculate the linear interpolated value between A and B? I can think of two methods:

Alternative 1:
Interpolated value = `((A << 8) + (B - A) * F) >> 8`
*(Will only work when B >= A, but I could wrap it in an if/else and swap A and B if A > B)*

Alternative 2:
Interpolated value = `A + (B - A) * (F / 256)`

Does it even matter which one I choose or would the compiler optimize them identically anyway?

Is there an even better method that involves no multiplication or division?

EDIT: Changed denominator in `alternative 2` from `255` to `256`

Comment: The alternatives are not equivalent. Alternative 1 includes an extra A term compared to Alternative 2.

Comment: Well yes, it certainly does :) thank you, removed it now. Now they should yield the same result.

Comment: Why would division by 256 with `(B - A) * F) >> 8` expected to be the same as division by 255 in `(B - A) * (F / 255)`?

Comment: @chux That is probably a typo as well.

Comment: Even with `/256`, assume `A==0` Certainly `(B * F) >> 8` gives different results than `B * (F / 256)`.  Since the 2 ways are not functionally equivalent. OP should use the one with the desired functionality.  I'd consider `A + ((B - A) * F) >> 8)` if `B >= A`

Comment: Yes `255` should be `256`. And I see now that it wont work if `B < A`. I could of course check that before the calculation and switch them. But I don't get why `((A << 8) + (B - A) * F) >> 8` won't work when `A < B` and `A == 0``?

Comment: (F / 256), where F is 8 bit integer (I. e. always less than 256) always gives 0

Comment: try this: A + (((int16_t) ((int16_t)B - A) * F + 128)  >> 8)

Comment: @AterLux Ah yes, it will get truncated. Didn’t think of that. Then I guess the question is, how costly 16-bit multiplication is compared to floating point division.

Comment: As far as I can see 8-bit*8-bit to 16-bit is one instruction on the m328 while anything including floating point arithmetic requires a significant number of  calls to expensive library functions.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that

- `F` is in 1/256 per count (and cannot completely express 1)
- `A`, `B` and `F` are `uint8_t`

the linear interpolation could be

```
uint8_t I = A + (uint8_t)(((int16_t)(B-A) * F) >> 8)
```

If you want that `255` expresses `1.0` then you have to divide by 255 instead of shifting but i guess i would handle the `one case` differently. eg by using 16bit for `F` and check for the highbyte before using the above formular with the lower byte if with its less than one.

The above line is nearly exactly the same as your Alternative one but since `A` and `B` are 8bit then the interpolated result cannot exceed the 8bit range, so the addition can be done using uint8_t.

Your alternative 2 always gets `A` as result since the second multiplicand (`F/256`) is always zero.